# Why is it when I run sequelize db:migrate migrations don't work but if I do sudo sequelize db:migrate?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, sequelize.js

When I run `sequelize db:migrate`, I get this error

> ERROR: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND 127.0.0.1

but when I use sudo e.g. `sudo sequelize db:migrate`, it works fine.

I have tried changing user permissions but nothing works if I do not use sudo, which I know it is not good for security reasons.